# Synonym for widely acknowledged?

Tags: synonyms

Is there another word for widely acknowledged? I'm writing a paper and I can't find a better word for widely acknowledged, but it is already used by my source

Comment: Provide an example sentence with a blank where you can fill the word you are looking for.

Comment: I would also like more information about why "widely acknowledged" being used by your source makes it unusable in your paper.  In some situations using a phrase too often can seem awkward, but that's very dependent on context and quantity.

Answer (score 1):

One option is the noun [**consensus**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consensus), or general agreement within a certain community.

> **Consensus** opinion is that Denali is the most impressive mountain in North America.
>
> There is **consensus** that cardiopulmonary resuscitation alone is unlikely to start the heart.
>
> **Consensus** holds that the *Dred Scott* verdict was a low point in U. S. Supreme Court decisions.

Answer (score 0):

How about *commonly recognized*? (See the many examples of usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commonly+recognized%22&num=100&tbm=bks&hl=en&sa=X&as_q=&nfpr=&spell=1&ved=0ahUKEwiNp87WuvbaAhVikuAKHWvXDWwQvwUIEQ).)